# Java static Lists in Android

Tags: java, android, list, android-listview

I have a static List in a model class:

```
public static List<HomePageOptions> homePageOptions = Arrays.asList(
    new HomePageOptions("Title1_1", "Title2_1"),
    new HomePageOptions("Title1_2!", "Title2_2"),
    new HomePageOptions("Title1_3", "Title2_3"),
    new HomePageOptions("Title1_4", "Title2_4")
);
```

where HomePageOptions is defined:

```
public class HomePageOptions
{
    String Title1;
    String Title2;

public HomePageOptions (String title1, String title2)
{
    setTitle1(title1);
    setTitle2(title2);
}

//regular setters and getters
}
```

I have an activity that opens as such:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(HomePageOptions ho : PharmacyModel.homePageOptions){
        values.add(ho.getTitle1());
    }
 }
```

The for loop is giving me an ExceptionInInitializationError.  I come across no problems when i create a regular List right before the for loop, but I would like to keep this structure in the model class.  I've been trying to find a solution as to why this is.  My guess is the static modifier on the List homePageOptions.  Can anyone help?

Here's what the debugger is saying

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ExceptionInInitializerError))   
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
HomeActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 33  
HomeActivity(Activity).performCreate(Bundle) line: 4465 
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1049   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1920    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1981 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 123    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1147  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4424    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

and LogCat

```
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at com.allgoodpeopleus.rootsoflife.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:24)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at ROLModel.Parameter.setValue(Parameter.java:91)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at ROLModel.Parameter.<init>(Parameter.java:21)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     at ROLModel.PharmacyModel.<clinit>(PharmacyModel.java:77)
06-20 04:08:06.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: and why it is static?

Comment: c# port of a large static class, made of all static objects.  I'm cool with making it not static, but need help on how to port that

Comment: Try not using same name `HomePageOptions` for list and class name

Comment: tried it, still have the same problem.  the debugger shows what's contained in PharmacyModel.homePageOptions and it's right.

Comment: i think that your problem is that the name of your HomePageOptions list is the same as the name of your class. which should not be the same. Moreover variable names always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @BBH1023 so where exactly is `ExceptionInitializationError` coming as you told that debugger is showing values correctly.

Comment: @sujithvm the problem highlights the line for(HomePageOptions ho : PharmacyModel.homePageOptions)

Comment: It's not because of class name and all. Post your logcat, then it will be clear to all. And point out the line where you're getting exception.

Comment: @BBH1023 I ran the same code locally and it seems to run fine. Are you missing something here from original code?

Comment: @BBH1023 are you using any library?

Comment: no library.  this is Android 4.0 i am debugging on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class PharmacyModel contains the public static List homePageOptions.  Elsewhere in the class, I have several instances of the class Parameter:

```
public static Parameter Age = new Parameter("Age", 30, "years");
```

where

```
public class Parameter {

public Object Value;

public Parameter(String name, Object defaultValue, String units) {
    setValue(defaultValue);
    //set others
}

ParameterChangedEvent listener;
public void addListener(ParameterChangedEvent event){
    listener = event;
}

public void setValue(Object value) {
    Value = value;  

    listener.ValueChanged();
}
```

Because calling setValue in the constructor, listener is null causing the problem.  The error manifested itself in the List, but nothing was wrong with that List or HomePageOptions.  The solution is to change to line

```
listener.ValueChanged();
```

to

```
if(listener != null) listener.ValueChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

this

```
public HomePageOptions (String title1, String title2)
{
    setTitle1(title1);
    setTitle2(title2);
}
```

should be

```
public HomePageOptions (String title1, String title2) {
    Title1 = title1;
    Title2 = title2;
}
```

Comment: still having the same problem when i implement this

Comment: is public static List<HomePageOptions> homePageOptions in your HomePageOptions POJO ?

Comment: could you add the code of PharmacyModel then ? The bug is probably buried there.

Comment: Look for other static members in PharmacyModel, methods and constructors wouldn't cause this problem. P.S. you shouldn't accept this answer, as the code i posted isn't the proper answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I found the error was a null pointer exception in another class.

Comment: I could ask *why?*. When answering, **consider explaining the reasons why you are providing that solution, and, of course, explain it!**

Comment: @Victor i posted the why.  now i can accept my own answer, in 2 days.

Comment: You aren't actually explaining why your provide this solution. You should mention something like *it is better because...* or *this works because...*. Also, you have to keep in mind that you are doing this for the entire community and for the ones not in it, not only for yourself.